# jQuery - creating the first dynamic page before executing a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I build a dynamic (one) page multi select  questionnaire .

I have to display the first page with "Hello" and a button which moves me to the first question.

I am using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {


        function Question(q,correactA,array){
            this.question=q;
            this.correct_a=correactA;
            this.answers=array;
        }
        multiQ= new Array();
        for (i=0;i<5;i++){
            var q = json.questions[i].question;
            var corA= json.questions[i].correct_answer;
            var a = json.questions[i].answers;
            var aString = "";
            Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {aString += a[k] ;})
            multiQ[i]=new Question(q,corA,a);
        }

        updateQuestion(0);



    });
});
```

The updateQuestion is a function which change dynamically the questions&answers.

How can I display the "first" page with "Hello" and a button which moves me to the first question.
This button should be displayed only in the beginning.

Comment: do you have the html markup you're referencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put your ajax function right in document.ready, but name it and call it when needed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function myFunction() {
        $.getJSON("data.json", function(json) { ... });
    }

    $('#myButton').click(function() {
        myFunction();
    });
});
```